# preventing data from being freed when vector goes out of scope

Tags: c++, matlab, scope, stdvector

Is there a way to transfer ownership of the data contained in a std::vector (pointed to by, say T*data) into another construct, preventing having "data" become a dangling pointer after the vector goes out of scope?

EDIT: I DON'T WANT TO COPY THE DATA (which would be an easy but ineffective solution).

Specifically, I'd like to have something like:

```
template<typename T>
    T* transfer_ownership(vector<T>&v){
    T*data=&v[0];
    v.clear();
    ...//<--I'd like to make v's capacity 0 without freeing data 
}

int main(){
    T*data=NULL;
    {
        vector<double>v;
        ...//grow v dynamically
        data=transfer_ownership<double>(v);
    }
    ...//do something useful with data (user responsible  for freeing it later)
   // for example mxSetData(mxArray*A,double*data) from matlab's C interface
}
```

The only thing that comes to my mind to emulate this is:

```
{
    vector<double>*v=new vector<double>();
    //grow *v...
    data=(*v)[0];
}
```

and then data will later either be freed or (in my case) used as mxSetData(mxArray*A,double*data). However this results in a small memory leak (data struct for handling v's capacity, size, etc... but not the data itself of course).

Is it possible without leaking ?

Comment: That's pretty confusing. Also, try asking in a C++ forum.

Comment: mxSetData and mxArray are part of the matlab C interface (via C mex files).

Comment: Yes but it isn't really a Matlab *question* -- People knowing Matlab coming here to help you won't be able to contribute anything unless they know C++.

Comment: @spirov, I suggest clarifying your questions a little, because, while the answers are answering your question, they seem unclear on why you are asking.  As far as I can tell you want to know two separate things (1) How to keep the memory in your vector live after the function exits (i.e. how to store it off the stack) and (2) How to pass the contents of the vector to an external API *without copying*.  I think the first is clear from your question but the second is not.

Comment: Yes, I would like (1) although not necessarily storing it in the stack (the external API accepts dynamically created memory), and (2) (but that part is easy, I just give &v[0]).

Answer (score 7):

A simple workaround would be swapping the vector with one you own:

```
vector<double> myown;

vector<double> someoneelses = foo();

std::swap( myown, someoneelses );
```

A tougher but maybe better approach is write your own allocator for the vector, and let it allocate out of a pool you maintain.  No personal experience, but it's not too complicated.

Comment: Simple, "clean" and very effective from perfomance perspective solution. myown can be created on heap or somewhere else, in order to live after someoneelses is out of scope.

Comment: or even shorter: `foo().swap(myown);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the custom allocators. I inherited allocator<T> into a allocator_derived<T> with custom behavior (being careful not to delete if some flag is set by the user, ie just before releasing the vector). This works great and doesn't leak with some care taken... on some systems but not all unfortunately. For example it works on mac (gcc 4.2.1) but on 64bit Linux (gcc 4.3), the vector declared as vector<T,allocator_derived<T> > doesn't even seem to use the derived behavior; I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 6):

The point of using a std::vector is not to have to worry about the data in it:

- Keep your vector all along your application;
- Pass it by const-ref to other functions (to avoid unnecessary copies);
- And feed functions expecting a pointer-to-T with `&v[0]`.

If you really don't want to keep your vector, you will have to copy your data -- you can't transfer ownership because `std::vector` guarantees it will destroy its content when going out-of-scope. In that case, use the `std::copy()` algorithm.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `&v[0]` construct for compatibility with C-like interface.

Comment: The third item is key, because passing the contents of the vector to the external functions without copying is big part of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

If your vector contains values you can only copy them (which happens when you call std::copy, std::swap, etc.). If you keep non-primitive objects in a vector and don't want to copy them (and use in another data structure), consider storing pointers

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
int main()
{
    double *data = 0;
    {
        vector<double> foo;
        // insert some elements to foo

        data = new double[foo.size()];
        std::copy(foo.begin(), foo.end(), &data[0]);
    }

    // Pass data to Matlab function.
    delete [] data;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you don't want to copy data between containers, but want to transfer ownership of data between containers, I suggest using a container of smart pointers as follows.

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<double> > doubles;
    InitVector(doubles);

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<double> > newDoubles(doubles);
}
```

You really can't transfer ownership of data between standard containers without making a copy of it, since standard containers always copy the data they encapsulate.  If you want to minimize the overhead of copying expensive objects, then it is a good idea to use a reference-counted smart pointer to wrap your expensive data structure.  `boost::shared_ptr` is suitable for this task since it is fairly cheap to make a copy of it.